# UINavigationController addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UINavigationController class, I want to add on a button with the method addSubview but its not working

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UIButton *testbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90,28,20)];
        [self.view addSubview:testbtn];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: how do you call this class? Are you sure this method is fired?  did you make sure you call `alloc initWithNibName:` before calling this class?

Comment: More importantly, what feature are you trying to implement?  Where will this button be and what is it's function? To me, this would determine where this code would live and/or allow us to suggest a better way to implement the feature you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can add a button to a `UINavigationController` - it doesn't actually have a view of its own. The `UINavigationController` is more of a behind-the-scenes organizer for holding and displaying other `UIViewController`s.

You'll need to take your `[self.view addSubview:testbtn]` and put that in the code of a `UIViewController`, instead of in the code for the `UINavigationViewController`. And as David Doyle pointed out in his answer, it's considered better practice to put something like that in `viewDidLoad` rather than in `initWithNibName`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume because you're trying to do this on a navigation controller, you want a bar button item on the toolbar.  You need to do this in the UIViewController, not the UINavigationController:

```
UIBarButtonItem * doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];
```

Also, you should grab a cup of coffee and read through the "overview" section of the [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It'll take about 10 minutes and you'll be happy you did.

If I'm wrong, and you do want a UIButton (not a UIBarButtonItem), you also need to do that in a UIViewController subclass.  Also, you should use its factory method, not a typical alloc/init:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 90,28,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a View Controller's view, its not a good idea to do so in the init method. The nib file that extracts the resources that create the View Controller's view takes a small amount of time to complete.

You're better off modifying the View Controller's view by overriding the method -[UIViewController viewDidLoad] like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  UIButton *testbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90,28,20)];
  [self.view addSubview:testbtn];
}
```

Comment: nothing has changed, even in viewDidLoad, my class is
@ DetailImagesViewController interface UINavigationController
I feel that addSubview not working